# Closure of linear Lie Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

While reading Vinberg, I found the following theorem (see image). In its proof it is said that two open sets of $\overline{G}$ are intersected, where $G$ - is linear subgroup of $GL_n$ and $\overline{G}$ its closure in $GL_n$.

Do i miss something? Many thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: So my question is why $gG$ and $G$ have non empty intersection? ($g$ lies in $\overline{G}$)

Comment: This author must be using some odd definitions. If $\alpha$ is an irrational number, the subgroup $G\subset GL(2,\mathbb C)$ consisting of diagonal matrices with diagonal entries $(e^{it},e^{i\alpha t})$ for $t\in \mathbb R$ is a Lie subgroup (by most people's definition), which is neither closed in $GL(2,\mathbb C)$ nor open in $\overline G$.

Comment: Which book (encyclopaedia volume?) of Vinberg is this? I cannot find it.

Comment: It is " a course in algebra", volume 56 AMS, page 475

Comment: @JackLee, thank you for your example, i'll try to consider it in more detail. But is $G$ open (in $\mathbb{C}^2$) and smooth manifold (if so, it's Lie group as in  Vinberg)? i didn't find the simple way to show it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "is $G$ open (in $\mathbb C^2$)" -- $G$ is a subset of $GL(2,\mathbb C)$, not $\mathbb C^2$.  (It is a subset of the two-dimensional complex subspace consisting of diagonal matrices, but that's essentially irrelevant here, and it's not an open subset of that space either.) This $G$ is not open in $GL(2,\mathbb C)$. It's an immersed but not embedded $1$-dimensional real submanifold.

Comment: @JackLee, Lie group in the question is hausdorff topological space with the group structure, such that every its point has neighbourhood homeomorphic to open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, i  think that submanifold should be an embedding also..and $G$ is open in $\overline{G}$ also

Comment: Well, these are very nonstandard definitions. Just be aware that using most common definitions of Lie group, the theorem you quoted is false.

Comment: @JackLee, thanks, i'm very new to this subject right now, but thanks a lot and for the nice example also